# Show tile layer within a certain area of the map

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

How do I show a tile layer within a certain area of the map? Tried using "extent" option, but it didn't work for me.

This is how I tried to do it:

```
var polygon = rm.getCurrentRegion().getData().polygon; //get a polygon
var extent = new ol.geom.Polygon([polygon]).getExtent(); //convert it to an extent
let newLayer = new CommonMap.TileLayer({
            type: LayerTypes.CUSTOM_WMS_LAYER + ('_' as any) + Base.getUid(),
            group: LayerGroups.CUSTOM_WMS_LAYERS,
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: `/maps/get?url=${this.url}` + query,
                params: $.extend(
                    { 'LAYERS': layers.map(l => l.key).join(',') },
                    styles ? { 'STYLES': styles.map(s => s.key).join(',') } : {}
                ),
                wrapX: true,
                projection: mm.getMap().getView().getProjection()
            }),
           extent: extent //doesn't work
        });
newLayer.setExtent(extent); //doesn't work
```

Comment: Could you add a code that shows how you tried?

Comment: yep,added it above

Comment: does your projection between layer(or map) and extent set the same?

Comment: I set projection of the map explicitly in TileLayer's options in order to make sure that projections are the same, but it still doesn't work. Added above how I did it.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean just having same projection. if one projections is not for the other one, you should transform the projection to have the same. I guess your layer and your view are different projection based. like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JyjOVq

Comment: I think so too, otherwise there is no reason for it to not work. Just need to figure out projection of the layer I'm trying to receive. Thanks a lot.